# Match a line and return a previous line before the match containing a pattern

Tags: sed

I'm writing a bash script for which in a file containing several entries where each entry has this structure:

```
Id: 33239
Folder: /Contacts/Holder/Center
Date: 04/17/20 13:17
Revision: 34011
Attrs:
  firstName: Name
  lastName: First Second
  mobilePhone: +345555555
  fileAs: 2
  jobTitle: Médico
  company: some company
  email: test_1@somedomain.com
```

I need to find the "Id" of the Item associated to a specific "email". For doing that, I'm trying to use "sed" with a hold. But I fail to achieve my objective. This is what I have so far, but I'm not getting the results I need.

```sh
id=$(grep $usuario -B20 /tmp/contactos \
    | grep "Folder: /Contacts/Holder" -B2 -A20 \
    | sed -n "/^Id: /h;/^  email: $usuario/{g;p;}" \
    | awk '{print $2}')
```

With this I'm trying to:

`id=` - assign the value to a variable I will use later on the script

`$(grep $usuario -B20 /tmp/contactos` - Get all the lines in the file, where the email appears, and also getting 20 lines before it. This is because the email appears associated with more than one `Id` an undetermined number of lines below the `Id itself.

`grep 'Folder: /Contacts/Holder' -B2 -A20` - I filter again, trying to get now only the results for the Ids for that email in a specific "folder path".

`sed -n '/^Id: /h;/^  email: $usuario/{g;p;}` - This is the part that is not working and I don't know how to fix it. Here, I try to return the line containing the `Id:` associated with the email. Something like: `Id: 33239` in this example.

`awk '{print $2}')` - Just me trying to print only the number from that line (`33239`).

Can anyone please help to understand how I can do it with sed` or if any other option is given, it will be also more than welcome :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: something like `awk '$1=="email:" && $2=="test_1@somedomain.com"{print id} $1=="Id:"{id = $2}' input_file` ?

Comment: This works great! No...I don't feel bad that I wasted 2 hours in something you solved in 2 minutes (you can't hear it but there is a lot of irony in that :P). Could you please let me know how it operates? I think this kung-fu will be very usefull for other things too. Thank you very much!

Comment: well, I could solve it easily because I've come across such a problem before and been using awk for a few years now.. see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for learning resources

Comment: Please clarify whether the number of *Attr:* items is constant, (there are 7 in the example), or might vary, (*i.e.* more or less than 7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sed command should extract it:

```sh
sed -n '
    /^Id: / {                 # If the line starts with "Id: "
        s///                  # Remove the "Id: "
        h                     # Store what is left in the hold space
    }
    /^  email: '"$email"'/ {  # If the line starts with "  email: " plus the email
        x                     # Swap pattern and hold space
        p                     # Print pattern space
        q                     # Stop processing
    }
' infile
```

where `$email` is the shell variable containing the escaped version of `test_1@somedomain.com`:

```sh
raw='test_1@somedomain.com'
email=$(sed 's|[]/.*^$\[]|\\&|g' <<< "$raw")
```

This escapes the sed special characters `.*/^$[]\`.

Or, more compact:

```
sed -n '/^Id: /{s///;h};/^  email: '"$email"'/{x;p;q}' infile
```

macOS sed requires an extra `;` before each closing `}`.

And yes, it's probably easier with awk

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!!! This also works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '$1=="email:" && $2=="test_1@somedomain.com"{print id} $1=="Id:"{id = $2}' input_file
```

- default field separator splits on spaces/tabs/newlines and removes leading/trailing spaces from field contents
- `$1=="email:"` checks if first field content is exactly `email:` (this is string comparison, not regexp)
- `$1=="email:" && $2=="test_1@somedomain.com"` if both conditions are satisfied, print `id` variable
- `$1=="Id:"{id = $2}` this saves the `id` value whenever first field is `Id:`

Here, I've used hard-coded string value for email to be checked, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) to know how to pass shell variable

Answer (score 2):

In the larger picture, you are trying to chain together conditions on the Folder and Email to produce an Id.  So `awk` is a better choice for solving the whole problem.  If your Bash script can prepare the script below, then you can invoke it like this:

> `id=$(awk -f /tmp/script.awk -v usario=test_1 /tmp/contactos)`

Here is the content that your Bash script should write to `/tmp/script.awk`:

```
/Id:/   { id=$2; folder="" }
/Folder:..Contacts.Holder/  { folder=$2 }
/email:/    { if (match($2, "^" usario "@") && folder != "") print id }
```

You should guard against the "matching prefix" problem.  Example is to find "juan" without also matching "juanita".  That's why the script uses the `match()` function with a regular expression that evaluates like `match($2, "^juan@")`.  That will match exactly "juan@domain.com" without matching "juanita@domain.com" or "somejuan@domain.com".

Note: The `awk` syntax concatenates strings and variables that are separated by spaces.  It "takes some getting used to" as they say.  You can add parenthesis around `"^" usario "@"` if that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Here are two silly pure `bash` methods, (no external utils), the general method requiring a constant number of field names and attributes, and (for the first method only) a relatively short input file:

1. ```
   printf '%0.0s%s%0.0s %s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s'\
       '%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s'\
       '%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s%0.0s %s\n' $(<infile) | 
       while read Id Folder email; do 
           [[ $email == test_1@somedomain.com && 
              $Folder == /Contacts/Holder/Center ]] && 
           echo $Id
       done
   ```

   How it works:  after the `printf`, what's fed to `while` looks like:

   ```
   33239 /Contacts/Holder/Center test_1@somedomain.com
   ```
2. The same thing can be done by using `read` a lot:

   ```
   while read a Id && read a Folder && read && read && read &&
         read && read && read && read && read && read && 
         read a email; do
         [[ $email == test_1@somedomain.com &&
            $Folder == /Contacts/Holder/Center ]] &&
         echo $Id
   done < infile
   ```

Comment: Pure shell methods are inefficient of course, but may be useful when the job is trivial and resources are very low, *e.g.* embedded systems.